# How can I get the filled color value in a WPF rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf, fill, rectangles

For example,Consider:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Fill = Brushes.Cyan;
```

Can I get the color value from a rect like this?
I tried to extract color values, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you need to cast Fill to correct Brush class, since Brush does not have color property (you need to cast it to SolidColorBrush):

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Fill = Brushes.Cyan;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((SolidColorBrush)rect.Fill).Color);
```

There are [different brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview) in WPF, for some of them Color does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
But I got this exception.
Additional Information: Type object 'System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush' can not be cast to type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush'.

Comment: You have to use pattern matching and check which type brush is and get relevant information from your brushes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching